# Example of a rational function such that : $(f(x))^{3} + (g(x))^{3} + (h(x))^{3}=x$

Tags: number-theory, functions, examples-counterexamples

Can any one give me example of: *rational functions* $f, g$ and $h$ with rational coefficients such that

$$(f(x))^{3} + (g(x))^{3} + (h(x))^{3}=x$$

Also, if anyone knows a procedure for constructing such examples, I would be happy to learn them as well.

> **Added:** Can we find rational functions $f$ and $g$ such that $(f(x))^3+(g(x))^3=x$

Comment: I don't know the answer, but by clearing denominators, you reduce this to $f(x)^3+g(x)^3+h(x)^3=x q(x)^3$, for *polynomials* with *integer coefficients*. This may be easier to think about. Setting $x=1$, you get an integer solution of $a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3$. This [paper](http://www.math.psu.edu/vstein/preprints/Rachel11.ps) is relevant then. Also, by setting $x=0$, you get Fermat's equation for exponent 3, which only has trivial solutions. In particular, $x$ divides one of $f$, $g$, $h$. Not that it helps...

Comment: Another observation is that (using lhf's notation) we must have all coefficients of $q(x)$ divisible by $3$. This is obtained by modulo 3 on both side, so we get $(f+g+h)^3=xq^3$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$, but $x$ is not a perfect cube, so this happens only when both sides are zero.

Comment: Start with $f(x)^3+g(x)^3+h(x)^3=x q(x)^3$.  Suppose $q(x)$ has degree $k$.  Then the RHS is asymptotic to $cx^{3k+1}$ as $x \to \infty$.  But the LHS is asymptotic to $dx^{3m}$ unless there is cancellation of the highest term... By exponent 3 of Fermat, that means two of the terms have higher degree than the third, and their highest terms are negatives.

Answer (score 7):

$(a^4-2a)^3+(a^3+1)^3+(2a^3-1)^3=(a^4+a)^3$

There are more at http://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/010 Section 2.

This is Number Theory, not real analysis.

Comment: How does that solve the problem? Ie, how do you get $a$ (not $a^3$) on the RHS?

Comment: @Gerry: Ok, one can always edit the Tags if he/she feels that it's wrong.

Comment: @lhf: In the page linked by Gerry you have several solutions and links as: $(m^3-3^6n^9)^3  + (-m^3+3^5mn^6+3^6n^9)^3  + (3^3m^2n^3+3^5mn^6)^3$ $= m(3^2m^2n^2 +3^4mn^5+3^6n^8)^3$.

Comment: @Esteban, ah, that's more like it! Perhaps you should promote this comment to an answer.

Comment: Apologies to all, the equation I posted is relevant to $f^3+g^3+h^3=1$, and not to what was actually wanted,  $f^3+g^3+h^3=x$

Comment: Note that there is no solution to $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \equiv \pm 4 \pmod 9$ in integers, as cubes are $0, \pm 1 \pmod 9$. So any solution to the original problem must have a common denominator that is always divisible by 3, as in Esteban's $3^2 m^2 n^2 + 3^4 m n^5 + 3^6 n^8.$

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested to know identities *are known* that can bring this higher:

$a_1(x)^3+a_2(x)^3+a_3(x)^3 = x$

$a_1(x)^5+a_2(x)^5+a_3(x)^5+...+a_6(x)^5 = x$

$a_1(x)^7+a_2(x)^7+a_3(x)^7+a_4(x)^7+...+a_8(x)^7 = x$

where the given number of addends $a_i$ are *rational functions* in terms of *x*, hence can be treated as "*Waring-like problems*". The case *k* = 3 mentioned by Esteban is cited in Yuri Manin's book *Cubic Forms* (but has been solved earlier by Ryley), while k = 5 and 7 have been solved by Choudhry. Interestingly, k = 7 involves polynomials where the coefficients have 33 digits! One has to solve the simultaneous equations,

$a^2+m^5b^2 = c^2+m^5d^2$

$a^4+m^3b^4 = c^4+m^3d^4$

which, for m = 2, can be reduced to an *elliptic curve* and has an infinite number of *integer* solutions (after multiplying out the denominators), though the "smallest" one has 33 digits.

P.S. If anybody can solve k = 9, I'll be interested to know.

See, "Waring-Like Problems" at http://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/001b.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

As ihf observed, you need

$f(x)^3+g(x)^3+h(x)^3=x q(x)^3$

On the left side you have three polinomials of degrees multiple of 3, on the right the degree is M3+1, thus something must cancel on the left side.

Without loss of generality, you can consider 2 cases:

Case 1: $deg(f)=deg(g) = deg(h)$. In this case, let $ax^k, bx^k$ and $cx^k$ be the dominant monomials in $f,g,h$. Then

$$a^n+b^n+c^n=0 \,.$$
which is not possible by Fermat last Theorem. So this is not possible.

Case 2: $deg(f)=deg(g) \geq deg(h)+1$.

Then $f=ax^k+bx^{k-1}+...$.  In order for the first two terms to cancel you need 
$g=-ax^k-bx^{k-1}+..$.  And I am stucked here.

This suggest that the simplest potential example would be something like:

$$f=x^2+ax+b \,;\, g=-x^2-ax+c \,;\, h(x)=dx+e \,.$$

The computations seem too long :)

Answer (score 0):

To the question added later:

$f(x)^3 + g(x)^3 = x$

It is not possible.

Setting $x$ to be $1^3, 2^3, \dots $ gives us a non-trivial solution to the diophantine equation $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$, since $f$ and $g$ can only have finitely many roots.

Comment: i am not able to comprehend your solution.

Comment: Are you using **FLT**

Comment: @Chandru: Yes, using Fermat's last theorem.